# Locking table through php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code

```
$LockQuery =  "LOCK Table `customers` WRITE";
$LockResult= mysqli_query($connection,$LockQuery);
```

When I run this script it doesn't lock customers table but it does in mysql console. It doesnt work in phpmyadmin either.
So is there any reason for that?
Here is phpmyadmin example
[image]

but

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error or something?

Comment: The lock is probably released when the session (the script in case of your script or phpMyAdmin...) ends, so you will never notice it until you let your script sleep for a while.

Comment: No it says that the query is successfully executed but it doesnt lock the table

Comment: What @jeroen is trying to say is that when your script exits, the locks get removed. Otherwise they would remain forever if you forgot to release them

Comment: @ArashSahel The same applies to phpMyAdmin, you enter your query, make a request, some phpMyAdmin script runs and executes the query, then ends and terminates it's mysql session, releasing the lock. Add a long sleep to your own script after locking to see if it really does not work.

Comment: when I lock The table in the top of the script I should Not be able to insert anything in that table until I excute the unlock table query

Comment: @jeroen how can I do that can you explane more about your idea

Comment: Seems way overkill locking the tables.How could any clients insert anything if you wont run any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html):

> If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or
>   abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the
>   session (transactional and nontransactional). If the client
>   reconnects, the locks will no longer be in effect.

You (or phpMyAdmin) start a session when you open a database connection in your script. When your - or phpMyAdmin's - script finishes, the database connection is automatically closed and *the session terminates*.

So if your script only runs for a short time, you will not notice the lock as it gets released almost immediately.

To test if your code works, you would have to open a database connection, execute the lock statement and add a `sleep(60);` (for example...) to hold the lock for a minute.